# Mostrar o ocultar div con javascript en una vista de ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Estoy trantando de hacer que al hacer clic en alguno de los items del navbar haga que se muestre un determinado div y oculte el resto pero no me sale.

Uso muy poco javascript por lo que no me estoy dando cuenta cual es el problema. 
Les dejo mi codigo, la informacion dentro de los divs esta vacía porque la saque para poder pegarla aquí.

```
<section>
<div class="card card-signin my-5">
    <div class="card-header text-center">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
            <a id="btn-informacion" class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Informacion</a>
            <a id="btn-notas" class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Notas</a>
            <a id="btn-documentos" class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Documentos</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="div-info" class="card-body text-center"> </div>
    <div id="div-notas" class="card-body text-center"> </div>
    <div id="div-doc" class="card-body text-center"> </div>
</div>
```

Y dentro del `@section scripts`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn_informacion").click(function () {
            $('#div-info').show();
            $('#div-notas').hide();
            $('#div-doc').hide();
        });
        $("#btn_notas").click(function () {
            $('#div-info').hide();
            $('#div-notas').show();
            $('#div-doc').hide();
        });
        $("#btn_documentos").click(function () {
            $('#div-info').hide();
            $('#div-notas').hide();
            $('#div-doc').show();
        });            
    });
</script>
```

Alguna sugerencia? Gracias.

Comment: Hola, tienes la librería de **jQuery.js** referenciada en tu Vista?, puedes indicar en la pregunta el código.

Comment: @RafaelAcosta Hola, tengo este bundle en el _Layout al fondo del body `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` y en el BundleConfig tengo registrado el bundle asi `bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.slim.min.js"));`. Y dentro de la carpeta Scripts tengo el archivo jquery.slim.min.js. Asi que si, creeria que esta bien referenciado.

Comment: Da algún error en la consola?

Comment: @matahombres `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
    at jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:2
    at jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js:2` Esos dos son los unicos, pero uno es del ckeditor que esta referenciado en un script pero lo saque ahora de la carpeta raiz para hacer pruebas y el otro es un script que no tiene nada que ver con esto

Comment: Sucede que al tirar ese error, todo el javascript siguiente deja de funcionar...

Comment: @fredyfx desactive esos scripts y sigue sin funcionar

Comment: utiliza un span en lugar de un anchor y prueba

Answer (score 0):

Podría probar eso?

***Html:***

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<div class="card card-signin my-5">
    <div class="card-header text-center">
        <nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
            <a id="btn-informacion" class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Informacion</a>
            <a id="btn-notas" class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Notas</a>
            <a id="btn-documentos" class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Documentos</a>
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div id="div-info" class="card-body text-center">DIV-INFO</div>
    <div id="div-notas" class="card-body text-center">DIV-NOTAS</div>
    <div id="div-doc" class="card-body text-center">DIV-DOC</div>
</div>

<script>        
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn-informacion").click(function () {
            console.log("#btn-informacion clicked");
            $('#div-info').show();
            $('#div-notas').hide();
            $('#div-doc').hide();
        });
        $("#btn-notas").click(function () {
            console.log("#btn-notas clicked");
            $('#div-info').hide();
            $('#div-notas').show();
            $('#div-doc').hide();
        });
        $("#btn-documentos").click(function () {
            console.log("#btn-documentos clicked");
            $('#div-info').hide();
            $('#div-notas').hide();
            $('#div-doc').show();
        });            
    });
</script>
```

Esto es **[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/diwekoqegi/edit?html,js,output)**.

Espero que esto ayude...

Answer (score -2):

Lo solucione de esta forma, la verdad es que no entiendo bien por que ahora funciona pero quedo asi

```
<div class="card-header text-center">
    <nav class="nav nav-pills nav-fill">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="btn-informacion" href="#">Informacion</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="btn-notas" href="#">Notas</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="btn-doc" href="#">Documentos</a>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="div-info" class="card-body text-center"></div>
<div id="div-notas" class="card-body text-center" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="div-doc" class="card-body text-center" style="display:none;"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn-informacion").click(function () {
            $('#btn-informacion').addClass('active');
            $('#btn-notas').removeClass('active');
            $('#btn-doc').removeClass('active');
            $('#div-info').show();
            $('#div-notas').hide();
            $('#div-doc').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn-notas").click(function () {
            $('#btn-notas').addClass('active');
            $('#btn-informacion').removeClass('active');
            $('#btn-doc').removeClass('active');
            $('#div-notas').show();
            $('#div-info').hide();
            $('#div-doc').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btn-doc").click(function () {
            $('#btn-doc').addClass('active');
            $('#btn-informacion').removeClass('active');
            $('#btn-notas').removeClass('active');
            $('#div-doc').show();
            $('#div-info').hide();
            $('#div-notas').hide();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Has probado la respuesta mía que funciona como se puede ver en JS Bin?

Comment: Si como así, qué no te gusta?

Comment: Yo no te vote negativo, tambien votaron negativo mi pregunta y respuesta, pero si, es algo parecido a lo que termine resolviendo yo asi que esta bueno